# Coloring the Sky

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

**Disclaimer:** I think I have a habit of making my riddles a bit too obscure so I'm trying to tone that down this time. Hopefully it won't end up being too easy and solved in about half a second. **The title is not a clue, just thematic with the colors - you could see it as a red herring.

> it was a bright morning, and Everyone here was happy. mostly. here's what happened:
>
> i got up, tuckered down a donut for breakfast, went to church to look at the sisters (don't judge me dick). it's clearly an Error but the doc predicted dexter wouldn't kill anyone, just like michael. E las robotico disgustationadad del sargio.
>
> obviously life is always better with a bit of color so we were wearing:
>   brown - crimson - red - orange - yellow - turquoise - blue - indigo - violet

What color is missing in the list above (what color should be in the list but isn't)?

*In efforts to avoid more answers just stating a random reason to back any color, the correct answer should also explain the full color list.*

**Hint**

> A Couple of days later, soMe redneck texAn arrIved with a tank and everything went to Hell. but we're stIll going, further thaN smallville or alMost anything else.

**New Hint**

> Six Pedals, Four Directions - there is no headlight fluid.

Comment: roygbiv.....pretty sure you hit all the colors there

Comment: ultraviolet! or maybe infrared...

Comment: it's a pretty normal color

Comment: Does the lack of capital letters means anything?

Comment: the letters' case is intentional.

Comment: @Spacemonkey White

Comment: @kanchirk: Why not black or grey?

Comment: I feel like the trivia tag is getting no love >_<, so much for being less obscure, I'm going to try and add stuff to make it less broad without just giving the answer.

Comment: I had someone look it over in case there was anything wrong with it, it seems I made a mistake, green was supposed to be brown, i updated the riddle accordingly (and no the answer isn't green)

Comment: Guys, green is a pretty normal colour that's missing from the list.

Comment: @Spacemonkey: You earlier had green in the puzzle, and there was no brown. This edit came later. Was 'green' put in by error? Or are both colours part of the original list?

Comment: Smallville, Dexter,.. maybe TV shows can lead somewhere...

Comment: @TroyAndAbed well that would certainly lead you a lot closer than anyone else so far

Comment: This should be purple, right? Red vs Blue, purple kryptonite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing color is

> pink

because the colors correspond to

> characters from the web machinima series [Red Vs. Blue](http://rvb.wikia.com/wiki/Red_vs._Blue_Wiki).  The characters are soldiers on opposing teams, each of whom appears in armor of their own color.

The story contains a cryptic reference to each

> of the main characters on the show, listed below with their colors:

:

> tuckered = Captain Lavernius Tucker = turquoise
>  donut = Private Franklin Delano Donut  = pink
>  church = Private Leonard L. Church = indigo
>  sister = Private Kaikaina "Sister" Grif = yellow
>  dick = Captain Richard "Dick" Simmons  = crimson
>  doc = Medical Officer Super Private First Class Frank "Doc" DuFresne = violet
>  dexter = Captain Dexter Grif = orange
>  michael = Captain Michael J. Caboose = blue
>  robotico = Lopez (a robot who speaks spanish) = brown
>  sargio = Colonel Sarge = red

Hints:

> "we're stIll going, further thaN smallville or alMost anything else" : the show is in its thirteenth season
>  "Six Pedals" is a running gag on the show: http://rvb.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Pedals

Additional Explanation (By OP):

> In the riddle, the 3 E's were a reference to the Electronice Entertainment Expo that was going on at the same time as this was posted, to direct people towards the gaming industry - a bit obscure I know.
>
> In the hint, the texan with the tank refers to the Character 'Tex' that appears halfway through the first season. Again the capital letters are: A,C,M,A,I,H,I,N,M that spell out Machinima, of which it is the first commercially successful. The second part of the hint refers to it being the longest continuous episodal series after Doctor Who, longest web series, etc.. In the second hint, headlight fluid is like the 6 pedals, a long running gag of the series.

Comment: I wanted to format the final block as a list, but I couldn't figure out how to do it and keep the spoiler covering.  If anyone knows how, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 5):

I think the missing colour is

> turquoise.
> It is missing in the sense that prior to the line enlisting the colours, all the other colours have their letters appearing in the preceding passage and they can be found in order too.
> Consider this for 'crimson':
> it was a bright morning, and Everyone was happy. mostly. here's what happened:
> i got up, tu**c**ked down a donut for b**r**eakfast, went to church to look at the s**i**sters (don't judge **m**e dick). it'**s** clearly an Err**o**r but the doc predicted dexter would**n**'t kill anyone, just like michael. E las robotico disgustationadad del sargio.
> By this logic, 'turqoise' cannot be found in the passage as there is no other word containing 'q' in the passage.

Comment: darn that's actually a pretty good find but not at all close to the answer. I edited the question : /  sorry. don't forget this is also a trivia riddle/puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

My guess and reasoning is,

> Since OP has stated in comments that the capitalization matters, I have decided to check the capital letters. Joining the capitalized letters gives EEE. A quick search for #EEE says that the color is a [very light gray.](http://www.color-hex.com/color/eeeeee)

Comment: the EEE are relevant but they are not a color code